# заполнение динамического одномерного массива вещественными числами

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    int n, count = 1;
    double numb;
    std::cout << "Введите количество чисел в массиве:";
    std::cin >> n;
    int *mass = new int(n);
    std::cout << "Введите числа в массиве:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << count << ":";
        std::cin >> numb;
        mass[i] = numb;
        count++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << mass[i] << "\n";
    }
    
}
```

хочу заполнить  массив вещественными числами, но пишет что возможна потеря при преобразовании "double" в "int", возможна потеря данных. И если вводить числа по типу 1.67, то он будет выводить 1. Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: если заменить int *mass = new int(n); на double *mass = new double(n);, то выводит правильно но выдает ошибку debug error

Comment: не преобразовывать в int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в

```
int *mass = new int(n);
```

У вас массив целых или вещественных? Ах, вещественных, т.е. `double`.

Но это не все. Думаете,

```
double *mass = new double(n);
```

спасет? Отнюдь. Это указатель на **одно число** со значением `n`. Для создания массива надо использовать *квадратные* скобки...

```
double *mass = new double[n];
```

Но и это может быть не всё. Поскольку вы объявили русскую локаль, то и числа должны вводить не с плавающей точкой, а, как локалью предусмотрено, с запятой...